# Variable Not Defined, Sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code is presented, in the book [Head First jQuery](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920012740.do).

```
function lightning_one(t) {
$("#lightning1").fadeIn(250).fadeOut(250);
setTimeout("lightning_one()", t);
}; // end lightning_one
```

It gets called with this line.

```
lightning_one(3000);
```

The observed behaviour is that the lightning fades in and out once, waits 3 seconds, fades in and out again, and then continues to fade in and out.  Firebug shows no javascript errors.

I understand why I see what I see.  I thought I would attempt to preserve the 3 second interval, so I changed this:

```
setTimeout("lightning_one()", t);  // nothing in the brackets
```

to this:

```
setTimeout("lightning_one(t)", t);  // t is in the brackets
```

When I refresh the page, the lightning fades in and out once.  Firebug tells me that variable t is undefined.

My question is, if the variable t is not defined after my change, how did the command run without error before I changed it?  It still has a variable named t.

**More Info**

Thank you everyone who wrote comments and answers.  For the record, in the "end" folder, the code becomes this:

```
    lightning_one();

   function lightning_one(){
$("#container #lightning1").fadeIn(250).fadeOut(250);
setTimeout("lightning_one()",4000);
    };
```

I haven't finished the applicable chapter yet so I don't know if the code change gets suggested later on.  As mentioned earlier, this might not be the best book out there.  However it's the one I bought and I am learning the fundamentals of jQuery from it.

Comment: They really pass a string to `setTimeout`? Throw that book far away.

Comment: I was thinking the same: I thought invoking functions this way was a bad practice... Not something that should be taught in a book!

Comment: I saw many words to that effect when I was trying to find the answer on my own.  Calling the function without quotes was one of my unsuccessful efforts.  For the purpose of my question though, I thought an accurate quote would be the best way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the first argument of `setTimeout` as a string is [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)-ed, meaning that it will looking into the outer scope of the function in which `t` is not defined. The first one is fine because you don't use any variables in the call, but the second is not because `t` is not defined outside the scope of the function. It is in fact local.

Advice: Don't use `eval` at all. In fact, you don't need the string argument. Use a function expression:

```
setTimeout(function() {

    lightning_one(t);

}, t);
```

Answer (score 2):

This **will** work:

```
setTimeout(function () { lightning_one(t); }, t);
```

I'm pretty sure invoking a function from a String (and letting it get evaluated) is a bad practice that should be avoided.